# Server/Client application do not communicate in all executions but only in some (Code unchanged)

Tags: java, quickfix

I have implemented a client and server. Both implement quickfix.Application and use ThreadedSocketInitiator/ThreadedSocketAcceptor to initiate/accept sessions. The client starts a thread that sends messages to the server. The call back function fromApp of the server, sends the response to client. Server is receiving requests from the client and responding to them, but the client is not receiving the responses. Note that this does not happen all the time. 2 out of 10 times, the same code works perfectly as expected and both client and server communicate. I do not understand what is going wrong.

Comment: Is this over TCP or UDP?

Comment: Your message log should tell you what's happening.  Without seeing your messages, it's impossible to diagnose this.